# Getting a blue bar in Firefox with GoDaddy's SSL?

Tags: ssl, firefox

I recently purchased a TurboSSL from GoDaddy. In Firefox, the address bar goes blue for a second, but then goes back to white. Is that because some images are coming from http:// and not https:// or is GoDaddy not supported with Firefox to actually be blue?

If GoDaddy doesn't work, what SSL providers have certs that will turn blue (preferably a cheap one)?

My other option would be the $150 Startcom EV cert to get the address bar green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes blue on my domains where I use a Godaddy cert.

I am pretty sure it is the non-secure elements on your page.  You could setup a test page on your site with no links to anything else to test.

Comment: I found a page that had no forms or anything, and using https:// made the bar go blue and stay blue.